# Martians are to Mars what Aryans are to?

Tags: pronoun, proper-noun, place-name

- "Terran" is to "Terra" what Aryan is to ______?
- "Venusians" are to "Venus" what Aryan is to ______?

This question is about the etymological origin of the pronoun Aryan, given that Terran depends on a place being colloquially called "Terra". Of or being from Terra. Never ever heard of a place called "Arya" or is there?

The first Aryan place name that comes to mind is "Valhalla", given that the Nordic and Baltic races were considered Aryan in the Third Reich, but am not familiar with any concrete links between Norse and Germanic mythology whatsoever.

Comment: There is no pronoun "Aryan" in German. It is unclear what you are asking and how it relates to the German language. You might have a question that fits on the History Stackexchange site but I'm not sure.

Comment: mistaking Aryans for Germanic language is pretty easy to do. Don't pretend to not know how the mistake can be made. Best answer has been chosen.

Comment: "Aryans" is clearly an English word. Don't pretend you didn't know that.

Comment: This is a joke taken seriously? Martians/Aryans -> Mars/Ars?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The OP says:

> The first Aryan place name that comes to mind is "Valhalla", given that the Nordic and Baltic races were considered Aryan in the Third Reich, but am not familiar with any concrete links between Norse and Germanic mythology whatsoever.

While term *Aryan* is usually associated with the white supremacy theories widespread in German-speaking countries in the first half of the XXth century, it is actually not of Germanic, but of [Indo-Iranian origin (link to Wikipedia article *Aryan*)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aryan):

> The term *Arya* was first rendered into a modern European language in 1771 as *Aryens* by French Indologist Abraham-Hyacinthe Anquetil-Duperron, who rightly compared the Greek *arioi* with the Avestan *airya* and the country name *Iran*. A German translation of Anquetil-Duperron's work led to the introduction of the term *Arier* in 1776. The Sanskrit word *ā́rya* is rendered as 'noble' in William Jones' 1794 translation of the Indian Laws of Manu, and the English *Aryan* (originally spelt *Arian*) appeared a few decades later, first as an adjective in 1839, then as a noun in 1851.

Thus, one could probably say that *"Venusians" are to "Venus" what Aryan is to Iran.* But this is just a guess - the question should be really addressed to the experts on ancient languages and Indo-Iranian history are in [Linguistics](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/) or [History](https://history.stackexchange.com/) communities.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. It really makes no sense though that Germanic caucasians idealize their race after Iranians, who are pretty much Semites neighboring the Jews. Someone please make this make sense, were 20. century Germans dumb?

Comment: @user610620 Iranians are not semites, Arabs are.

Comment: thus the placement of "pretty much neighboring" perojoratively. the question remains a white race trying to model themselves after black-haired brown skin iranians, while at the same time castigating anyone with black hair and brown skin originating in the surrounding areas of iran. make it make sense pls

Comment: This discussion definitely doesn't belong in German Language Q&A. You may fit in better in a politics or history debating forum.

Comment: @TilmanSchmidt I suppose it could be a legitimate question, if it asked about the origin of terms *Arier* and *arisch* in German. As it is now, it could be even in English community.

Comment: Agreed for the actual question, but not for the comments going off on a tangent about 20th century ideologies.

Answer (score 3):

"Aryan", or "Arier" in German, originally wasn't a term for people from a specific place, but for people speaking a specific language (or group of languages):

> Der Ausdruck Arier (...) ist unter anderem eine Selbstbezeichnung von Sprechern indoiranischer Sprachen.

[Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arier)

So it was originally a term speakers of [Indo-Iranian languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indo-Iranian_languages) used for themselves in ancient times, to contrast themselves from neighboring people who spoke other languages. We're talking about roughly 500 B.C. and earlier. Obviously, those people lived *somewhere*, but for a long time scholars couldn't agree on where exactly. This search for a (at least partially mythical) "Urheimat" (roughly "original homeland") played a role in the shift of the term from linguistics into far-right politics.

Because many centuries later, in the 19. and 20. century, the term was kind of occupied by white supremacists who were looking for a pseudo-scientific rationale for the idea of them being some kind of "superior race". *Very* broadstroke, the general concept was that back in the day, some Aryans supposedly travelled to Europe to "bring culture" to the people there. The white supremacists considered themselves descendants of those "Kulturbringer". And because of that, they were obviously superior to all those other lowly people...